# Java can anyone explain why this keeps throwing an error?

Tags: java

***Object Oriented programming***

sorry for the lack of clarity.

our teacher gave us this example its a **singleton and factory pattern** program combined however when I run it in java it keeps telling me that the class fromExperian doesn't exist. I've retyped it word for word in eclipse and double checked for anything different it's one program all in the same file.

- ***the issue:***

  I get an error message saying that the class doesn't exist even when it does.
  okay so this is the pdf document each screen shot is a page. So if I type into the scanner in the main I'll get fromExperian class doesn't exist, or fromTransUnion class doesn't exist etc.

It looks like it can't find the classes even though they are in the same file?

[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]
[image: page 3]
[image: page 4]
[image: page 5]
[image: page 6]

Comment: What error? in which line?

Comment: unrelated topic: suggest you always use class names beginning with UpperCase, methods beginning with lowerCase -- that's the Java convention and it gets confusing to see classes with lowercase names

Comment: PF.getPenColor();   I looked and the error doesn't show up until I run this line in the main.

Comment: Did you put all your classes into individual files? How did you name those files? Watch out for case-sensitivity!

Comment: One issue: `fromExperian` is an abstract class, so you can't instantiate it. Same with `fromTransUnion`.

Comment: and this isn't my code it's the example our teacher gave us in a PDF document I can send that to you if you want to take a look. I've copied it over into eclipse to run it and try to understand it but no luck so far lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me. But only as long as it exists in the **default package**!

You have to use `Class.forName(...)` with the canonical class name. So as long as you are not in the default package your error occurs.

```
penCheck = (pen)Class.forName(s).newInstance();
```

leads to your error if your class does not lie in the default package.

```
penCheck = (pen)Class.forName(fromExperian.class.getCanonicalName()).newInstance();
```

instead will always work.

And *yes* it also works when `fromExperian` is abstract.

Comment: What's the point of calling `newInstance` if you already have the class ? Why not simply do a `new fromExperian()` ? That makes the code irrelevant.

Comment: True that makes no sense. The author did not have the class but enters the class name as a string. In my example I only used the class to show that it works as long as you use the full class name including the package.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the company to `Experian`, you then try to instantiate the `fromExperian` class. That can't happen, as `fromExperian` is abstract.

You'll have to make your `fromExperian` class concrete by removing the abstract keyword, or create at least a concrete class named (which name starts with "from") that extends `fromExperian` and set the company name accordingly.

Comment: Sorry both classes are concrete in the original final that was me trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your files are. Make sure all your .java files are in the proper spots. I don't know the details but when you get this kind of error I believe it's because the JVM can't find the .class file that the compiler was supposed to have made. When you compile it check your classpath and make sure everything is in the right packages and what not. Your single_factory_pattern.class or fromExperian.class is the culprit.

Comment: All files are in one single file on the same page.

Comment: Which file though? In the default package? Either way pommes got's your answer I believe.